# I can't edit table that another table has a foreign key of it in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

This is my SQL code in MySQL:

```
create table Table1
(
  id varchar(2),
  name varchar(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


Create table Table1_Addr
(
  addid varchar(2),
  Address varchar(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (addid)
);

Create table Table1_sal
(
  salid varchar(2),
  addid varchar(2),
  id varchar(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (salid),
  index(addid),
  index(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (addid) REFERENCES Table1_Addr(addid),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Table1(id)
)
```

Table1 and Table1_Addr are two tables that Table1_sal has two foreign keys to these two tables.

My problem is that I can't change id field of Table1 and addid field of Table1_Addr

The error is:

```
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint
fails (`avl`.`table1_sal`, CONSTRAINT `table1_sal_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
REFERENCES `table1` (`id`))
```

Edited-The answer is:

```
create table Table1
(
  id varchar(2),
  name varchar(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


Create table Table1_Addr
(
  addid varchar(2),
  Address varchar(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (addid)
);

Create table Table1_sal
(
  salid varchar(2),
  addid varchar(2),
  id varchar(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (salid),
  index(addid),
  index(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (addid) REFERENCES Table1_Addr(addid)ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Table1(id)ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: That's the whole point of foreign keys. They prevent you creating (or causing) "orphan" records. Whatever update you're doing would cause a record to be orphaned, therefore the query is being denied.

Comment: How can I fix the problem? Is there another method I use?

Comment: what's to fix? Either remote the foreign keys so you can create all the orphans you want, or don't delete/update whatever record is causing this.

Comment: what is the query that failed?

Comment: I delete it in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ON UPATE CASCADE` after your foreign keys definitions

```
    FOREIGN KEY (addid) REFERENCES Table1_Addr(addid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Table1(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Create table Table1_sal
(
  salid varchar(2),
  addid varchar(2),
  id varchar(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (salid),
  index(addid),
  index(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (addid) REFERENCES Table1_Addr(addid) On Update cascade,
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Table1(id) On Update cascade
)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the foreign key to On Update cascade.Then all child rows will also be updated

```
     Create table Table1_sal
(
  salid varchar(2),
  addid varchar(2),
  id varchar(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (salid),
  index(addid),
  index(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (addid) REFERENCES Table1_Addr(addid) 
   On delete cascade On Update cascade ,
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Table1(id) 
   On delete cascade On Update cascade
)
```

Comment: Thank you I can edit the row but I can't delete it yet.

Comment: you have to on delete cascade too

Answer (score 0):

Your problem of not able to change primary keys of Table1 and Table1_Addr, being foreign keys of Table1_Addr, is the normal behavior of Relational Database, like MySQL,

Comment: Thank you. Then how can I delete a row if I need?

Comment: You need to delete all Table1_sal rows that referenced to the row of Table1 that you want to delete.  After then, you can delete the very row of Table1.